# Can't figure out how to show an android dialog

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, dialog

Im trying to get a dialog to display on my app, I followed the exact dialog tutorial on the android website https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html
(with some slight name changes) however it is rather ambiguous about where to put certain portions of code leading to my code not working. Im not sure what to do at this point.

**Dialog Fragment**

```
public class CreatePlayerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.player_name_dialog)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.player_name_dialog_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.player_name_dialog_no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                    }
                });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

**XML File** The button in question is id: button 6

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_start_new_game"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.hunte.assassin.StartNewGameActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_start_new_game">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:hint="Name Of Game"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColorLink="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
        android:id="@+id/Players" />

    <TextView
        android:text=" Players:"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:foreground="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="confirmFireMissles"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:foreground="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

    <Button
        android:text="Begin!"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity W/ show dialog method**

```
package com.example.hunte.assassin;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class StartNewGameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ListView lv;

    public void confirmFireMissiles() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new CreatePlayerDialogFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "missiles");
    }

    ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_new_game);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Players);

        // Instanciating an array list (you don't need to do this,
        // you already have yours).
        List<String> game_players = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++){
            game_players.add(players.get(i).name);
        }




        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                game_players );

        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }


}
```

This is what I thought would be the most logical implementation however my XML file does not seem to recognize my "confirmFireMissles" method and my activity file says that my method isnt used. Sorry for including so much code I just cannot identify where the problem may lie. Im only trying to get this to work so I can understand how to display a dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass View as parameter to `confirmFireMissiles()` method.

```
public void confirmFireMissiles(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new CreatePlayerDialogFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "missiles");
}
```

Comment: Well that did work, I could've sworn that I tried that but I suppose I did not. Thank you.